# How to place validator control message text just right to the control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have following HTML structure :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" class="textBox js-min" runat="server" />        
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="strtDtValidator" ControlToValidate="txtFrom" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter a date." Text="*" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="required" EnableClientScript="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>          
        <span class="label" id="">&nbsp;&nbsp;End:</span>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" class="textBox" runat="server" />        
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="endDtValidator" ControlToValidate="txtTo" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter a date." Text="*" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="required" EnableClientScript="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

It is displaying star both "*" symbol after the last textbox. How to place them correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you would like to see the "Please enter a date." text next to the TextBox then put Text="Please enter a date." for the RequiredFieldValidator. TheErrorMessage property is used if you have a ValidationSummary control, which will list all the errors.

Comment: Actually, i just want to put "*"

Comment: Then your example is correct, I just copy/pasted the code and it shows the "*" next to the TextBoxes when no value is provided. I guess it's a css class issue, since it worked for me.